# Old pup lunges at new dog

Tags: behavior

we are fostering a dog with the intention of adoption. We have had our first dog for a year and a few months. She is somewhat dog reactive but has gotten along with my parents dogs.

Our new pup is very calm. Every time he attempts to move to a new part of the house, our first pup lunges, growls, and barks at him, almost like she is snapping at him.

Is this just a territorial thing? How can I help stop her from doing it? Thanks!

Comment: Does it happen very often that you might treat the new foster dog better than your current dog causing jealousy?